# Suppose that $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and that $x \in X $. Justify the statement: $x \in f^{-1}({f(x)})$. Is ${x}= \bar f^{-1} ({f(x)})$ true?

Tags: functions

Suppose that $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and that $x \in X $.

Definition 5.1.1 states that we let $X$ and $Y$ be sets. A function $f$ from $X$ to $Y$ written $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a rule that pairs an element $x \in X$ with an element $y \in Y$, written $f(x) =y$ such that the following property holds.

$(( \forall x \in X)( \exists! y \in Y)[f(x) =y]$

Justify the statement: $x \in f^{-1}({f(x)}).$

$X$ belongs in the inverse of $f(x)$. The $f(x)$ is the image of elements in the domain.
 By Definition 5.1.8, if we let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ then the inverse of $f$ (or $f$ inverse denoted $f^{-1})$ is the pairing defined by the rule that if $f(x)=y$, then $f^{-1}(y)=x$.[...] all images of elements of the domain are in ${f(x) : x\in X}$

Is ${x}= \bar f^{-1} ({f(x)})$ true?

There is supposed to be {} on the x and f(x), but the latex wouldn't show it.

By definition 5.1.5, let $f: X \rightarrow Y$. The range of $f$ is the set ${y \in Y: (\exists x \in X), f(x)=y}. $

Recall that all images of elements of the domain are in ${f(x) : x\in X}$ . By definition 5.3.8, if we let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ for each set $B \in \mathcal P \left({Y}\right)$, then the function $\bar f^{-1}: \mathcal P \left({Y}\right)  \rightarrow \mathcal P \left({X}\right)$ is defined by $\bar f^{-1} (B)  = [x \in X: f(x) \in B]$.

I'm not even sure if I'm on the right track, but I have included some definitions that may be relevant to answering this question. For the second part, power sets are involved. So is it the power set {x} must equal or not equal to the power set inverse of the function on the right?!

Comment: Just as a note: `\{` is needed for braces, since braces by themselves do grouping things.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think thinking about power sets is really going to be helpful here (even if they are in the formal definition).  If you put the definition you gave together with the problem, you're trying to discover things about
$$\bar f^{-1}(\{f(x)\}) = \{a\in X\mid f(a) \in \{f(x)\}\}.$$
(I changed notation slightly since we had one too many $x$'s.)  But since $\{f(x)\}$ is a singleton set, you're really just looking at $f(a)=f(x)$. Does that guarantee that $a=x$?

Comment: I don't think so.. two different variables... unless $f(a)$ and $f(x)$ have the same values ... or in this case the same elements.

Comment: Can you think of a function where $f(a)=f(x)$ but $a\neq x$? If so, there's your counterexample.

Comment: like OH! the numerical values of a and x aren't equal but the function is? like I need to create a $f(a)$ function that equals to $f(x)$

Comment: so the a belongs in x.... the function a belongs to function x, but since there are these {} things ...

Comment: I know. what if we let $f(a) = \abs{a}$ and $f(x) = \abs{x}$. Then a = -5 and x = 5. The $f(a)$ and $f(x)$ will be equal, but $-5 \neq 5$